# Using less-css consts to avoid manual magic constants - always, or only in simple cases?

Tags: css, coding-style, less

I'm working on a page with existing layout, that was written in css a long time ago. Since we have less capabilities, I renamed it to .less, and am sprinkling it with LESS capabilities when appropriate.

One of my irks me in the original css is magic constants that depend on each other. Whenever I want to change the padding on an inner div, I need to change its width as well, to match the space it has remaining. So, thinking I was so cool, I went around and converted this knowledge into the language of LESS constants:

```
@mainContentPageWidth: 945px;
@widgetAreaWidth:220px;
@contentpagecontent-padding-right: 20px;
@contentpagecontent-padding-left: 10px;
@contentpagecontent-width:@mainContentPageWidth - @widgetAreaWidth - @
  contentpagecontent-padding-right @contentpagecontent-padding-left;
```

So now, I feel pleased with myself because I can edit any of these magic constants in one place only, without any need to calculate and adjust width of other elements.

The thing is ... I also feel this is a bit counter productive. To save me this minor annoyance when I change padding on an element, I added 5 new LESS constants, one of which is a big calculation, and made the original code harder to understand - you have to jump up and down in the LESS file to understand what's really going on (I defined all the constants at the top of the file).

So ... from your experience, what's a good balance to strike here between DRY/no-inter-dependent-magic-constant violations and writing simple concise code?

Comment: BTW, I just reverted this commit, and decided it's not worth it ... just looking for some wisdom from people who debated this before.

Comment: Voted to close as subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I'm just going to kinda rephrase/repeat what I said below. Think of this as writing class/method to connect to a database which take arguments with db credentials - it's better to store those credentials somewhere else and not hardcode them in the class/method, right? :)

But of course you can treat this in a more loose way - for your example, if you are 100% concerned that your layout will never change and your widths/paddings/margins won't change, go ahead and write them in a regular CSS way. But if you will want to change the same layout on one of the pages (or reuse this in another project), then it makes sense to define variables.

Your variables file can have sections for various areas of your site, it's just a matter of organizing it the way you think it's going to work for your project...

You wrote that you have to jump up and down to understand what's going on - well I don't quite understand you here. You define @variables, use them in class definition, and.. you stop worrying about it! NOW - If you wanna change it, you don't have to jump up and down to find that element declaration, go through other properties which you're not interested in, you just find the section for "Layout Variables" in your variables.less, and change it there! Compile to CSS and et voila!

Take a look at other .less files in Bootstrap project (same link as below), they have it organized in a good way, I use this library for a while now and it's just perfect.

---

Look at [this](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less) example :)

It is perfectly fine to write as many variables as you want, but it makes great sense to maintain it in a separate file.

Don't worry too much about writing too many variables because it all gets compiled into CSS and the @placeholders are going to be replaced by actual values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see what you mean ... but I think I'll vote to close this question as it has no objective, concrete answer.

Comment: @ripper234 i edited my answer a bit, not sure how can i explain it in a better way. if you wanna chat, let me know.